# How do I change what is shown when the UISegmentedControl index is changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a small issue with my segmented controller and trying to change the views shown to the user when clicking a new index.  I have code set to show text-boxes that the user would type into when the index is changed.  One issue is that I want to place text-boxes under the segmented controller evenly and the other issue is that when I click a new index in the controller, the prior text box is still on the screen, but I need it to show just the text box correlating to the specific index that is chosen.  The code is shown below where I created the segment controller and handled the switch of indexes as well as the creation of the text-boxes.

```
    let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Inventory", "Sale", "Expense"])
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        sc.layer.cornerRadius = 9
        sc.layer.borderWidth = 1
        sc.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        sc.layer.masksToBounds = true

        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }()

    //function to handle click of segmented control buttons
    @objc fileprivate func handleSegmentChange(sender: UISegmentedControl){
        print(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

        switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
        case 0:
            view.addSubview(myProduct)
        case 1:
            view.addSubview(myRetail)
        default:
            view.addSubview(myExpense)
            break
        }

    }

    let myProduct : UITextField = {
        let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 10))
        mp.placeholder = "Enter Product name"
        mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
        mp.backgroundColor = .white
        mp.textColor = .cyan

        return mp
        }();

    let myRetail : UITextField = {
        let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 20))
        mp.placeholder = "Enter Retail price"
        mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
        mp.backgroundColor = .white
        mp.textColor = .cyan

        return mp
        }();

    let myExpense : UITextField = {
        let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 30))
        mp.placeholder = "Enter Expense name"
        mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
        mp.backgroundColor = .white
        mp.textColor = .cyan

        return mp
        }();
```

Most of the solutions I have seen are outdated, which is why I am posting my own version here.  Thanks in advance for help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `tag` for each `UITextField` as below,

```
let myProduct : UITextField = {
    let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 10))
    mp.placeholder = "Enter Product name"
    mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
    mp.backgroundColor = .white
    mp.textColor = .cyan
    mp.tag = 11
    return mp
}()

let myRetail : UITextField = {
    let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 20))
    mp.placeholder = "Enter Retail price"
    mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
    mp.backgroundColor = .white
    mp.textColor = .cyan
    mp.tag = 12
    return mp
}()

let myExpense : UITextField = {
    let mp = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 320, width: 300, height: 30))
    mp.placeholder = "Enter Expense name"
    mp.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.line
    mp.backgroundColor = .white
    mp.textColor = .cyan
    mp.tag = 13
    return mp
}()
```

and then inside `handleSegmentChange`, remove any view with that tag before adding a new one as below,

```
//function to handle click of segmented control buttons
@objc fileprivate func handleSegmentChange(sender: UISegmentedControl){
    print(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)

    [11, 12, 13].forEach { self.view.viewWithTag($0)?.removeFromSuperview() }

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        view.addSubview(myProduct)
    case 1:
        view.addSubview(myRetail)
    default:
        view.addSubview(myExpense)
    }
}
```

For the position issue, you haven't set any frame to `UISegmentControl`. You can set `frame` as below to get the result shown,

```
let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Inventory", "Sale", "Expense"])
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    sc.layer.borderWidth = 1
    sc.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    sc.layer.masksToBounds = true
    sc.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 280), size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 30))

    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try a bit later today.  As for the frame of the UISegmentControl, it is currently placed in a stackview that has it sitting under the title in the navigation bar.  I am planning on removing it from the stackview, but if I do that to make the placement the same would i set the top anchor for the UISegmentControl to be the bottom anchor of the navigation controller?

Comment: Yes, it should be pinned at the top of the `view`.

Comment: Tested your solution and works perfectly, thank you so much !!